# Is there a reason as to why my locally hosted images aren't displaying on my site after uploading everything on GitHub?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, frontend

o I am brand new to Github, and frankly to programming in general. I created my own portfolio website (following a Youtube guide) and have been facing so many issues trying to understand terminals and then getting it up on Github, but I must learn Github so it's worth learning it even though there are other options to post your websites onto. But after getting everything on my repositories, everything looks normal when I look at the code but when I open my website hosted on GitHub called tyler-104.GitHub.io (my portfolio website), all my images that are local to my computer won't display.

My images that aren't local are displaying ( I have one for github and one for LinkedIn) and work as they should. I thought that I simply only had to upload my local images that are also inside my HTML code to my repositories would solve it, but it does not.

If you look at my site
(tyler-104.github.io)

none of the bigger images are being displayed even after uploading my local files to my repository (https://github.com/Tyler-104/tyler-104.github.io). More than that I have tried and created multiple repositories, uploaded, altered, and updated but nothing seems to work. My only guess is that since they are local they won't display.

Do you need to somehow use images that are already stored online to make it work? Basically, would I have to remove my locally stored images (that are on my Desktop for example) in my HTML and use internet links that I want to display on some sites like Unsplash? Or can I use local images stored images and they will still be displayed?

Comment: there isn't an `img` folder in the repo, all the folders are in the root?

Comment: I think so yes, img is my main folder, and then I have sub folders like 3D with bunch of images. I still dont' get what the problems is. I've also added an absolute path writing for example "https://tyler-104.github.io/img/git mv header/headerImg.png" but that still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The console of the [developer mode](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/) is full of 404 for URLs like:

```
GET https://tyler-104.github.io/img/3D/Grapes.webp: 404
                               ^^^^^ ?
```

But your repository does not have a `img` folder. It directly has [`3D/Grapes.webp`](https://github.com/Tyler-104/tyler-104.github.io/blob/af6b1529ffe53a5e32a29eeccfc36f77fcfbc278/3D/Grapes.webp).

So might need to create `img`, and [`git mv 3D img/`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) in it (the commit and push), to test if those images are displayed.

Comment: Hello, so I added the img in my repository, or rather I added the img that includes all those separate folders like 3D/Grapes.webp directly in my VSC into my tyler-104.github.io and then committed and pushed it, now when the file is in my repository I still get the same error. When you say git mv 3d, do you mean that I should rename the folder or something?

Comment: @TylerThomas No, I meant to use the [`git mv` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv). Your folders (moved into `img/`) should keep their original name (like `3D`)

Comment: @TylerThomas Great! Can you post an answer here to explain how you did solve it? That will help others.